# Get Numpy array from SHAPE@WKB token

Tags: arcpy, buffer, numpy, array, well-known-binary

I am trying to get a numpy array from the SHAPE@WKB token that is obtained either using FeatureClassToNumpyArray or cursors, however what I get does not make much sense.

Specifically I am interested in obtaining the xy coordinates that make up different polylines. Although I would like to generalize the question a bit more for any geometry.

For instance:

```
>>> x = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumpyArray(fcPolylines,['SHAPE@WKB'])
>>> np.frombuffer(x[0]['SHAPE@WKB'])
array([  1.62969277e-311,   1.69495090e-156,   3.83453941e+085,
         1.64947523e-156,   3.85098414e+085,   1.63156857e-156,
         3.85745948e+085,   3.21142670e-322,   0.00000000e+000,
         0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,
         0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,
         ...,
         0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,
         0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,
         0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,
         0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,
         0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000 ])
```

I'm really looking to get the same information that you get when requesting the SHAPE@XY token next to the `explode_to_points = True` argument:

```
>>> arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray("Perfiles",['SHAPE@XY'],explode_to_points=True)
array([([517465.97249554005, 4640473.617421979],),
       ([517467.13585821074, 4640570.8782546315],),
       ([517467.62161390204, 4640611.48898075],)], 
     dtype=[('SHAPE@XY', '<f8', (2,))])
```

After @mikewatt’s answer, I knew how to get what I want from the WKB attribute of an arcpy geometry object:

```
>>> polyline = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Perfiles",arcpy.Geometry())
>>> np.frombuffer(polyline[0].WKB[9:],np.float64).reshape((-1,2))
array([[  517465.9725,  4640473.6174],
       [  517467.1359,  4640570.8783],
       [  517467.6216,  4640611.489 ]])
```

However, although as seen this method does work when I extract the WKB from an arcpy object, it does not seem to work when I apply it on the extracted WKB as a token and I get the following error:

```
>>> x = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumpyArray(fcPolylines,['SHAPE@WKB'])
>>> x[0]['SHAPE@WKB']

>>> np.frombuffer(x[0]['SHAPE@WKB'][9:],np.float64).reshape((-1,2))
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: can't index void scalar without fields
```

Comment: You have to specify the data type, and there's more than just coordinates in the WKB (stuff you'll have to ignore when parsing the coords).  See here for an example with polylines:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401796/arcpy-polyline-shape-object-to-numpy-array/401808#401808

Comment: @mikewatt i have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring because `FeatureClassToNumpyArray` is returning the WKB as a void datatype, in contrast to a Python bytestring like `arcpy.Geometry().WKB` gives.  This means numpy isn't trying to interpret it as numerical data, so a lot of the methods it makes available for numerical data (like slicing) won't work.  So we can just round trip back through bytes:

`buff = x[0]['SHAPE@WKB'].tobytes()`

But if you inspect that you'll notice it might be longer than it should be, padded out to some length with null bytes.  We'll also have to figure out the correct slice of data we can feed into `np.frombuffer()`, so it doesn't try to digest garbage.  We'll have to go back and expand upon the more complete example from my previous answer:

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np

records = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(polyline_fc, ['SHAPE@WKB'])

dtype_struct = np.dtype([
    ('byteOrder', np.byte),
    ('wkbType', np.uint32),
    ('numPoints', np.uint32)
])
dtype_point = np.dtype((np.float64, 2))

for rec in records:
    # Convert from a void array to a bytestring we can slice up
    buff = rec['SHAPE@WKB'].tobytes()

    array_struct = np.frombuffer(buff[:dtype_struct.itemsize], dtype_struct)

    assert array_struct['byteOrder'] == 1
    assert array_struct['wkbType'] == 2  # This example is only for linestrings

    # Slice off the WKB header which describes the struct and the padding which
    # arcpy adds to the end of the string, leaving us with point data only.
    len_struct = dtype_struct.itemsize
    len_points = array_struct['numPoints'] * dtype_point.itemsize
    point_buff = buff[len_struct:len_struct + len_points]

    array_points = np.frombuffer(point_buff, dtype_point)

    print(array_points)
```

All this to say... it seems excessive to be writing your own WKB parser when you could just use the interfaces provided by arcpy's geometry objects.  Unless you reeeallly need to be eeking out some optimization then keeping is simple is usually better, even if it might be a tad slower.

Comment: Thank you, again you have resolved my question. Believe me I would avoid getting into the WKB cracking, but given my data sets I'm having some problems and with this I will be able to move a bit further.
On the other hand, in the previous answer he offered me two versions, one more extensive with validation and another without it, I have tried to adapt his current answer to also obtain the simplified version, however I have not been too successful. Would you know how to achieve it?

Comment: No problem.  Why are you attempting to reduce it?  It can't get any simpler [logic-wise] when parsing what comes out of `FeatureClassToNumpyArray`.  We're now required to parse the geometry description from the WKB for reasons mentioned in the answer, instead of assuming things about it and using a magic number to skip over it like in the "simple" [hackier, more failure-prone] version.  Parsing that won't be noticeably more expensive, nor will leaving the `assert` statements intact

Comment: Thank you, I will follow your advice. One last question, if I may.
How can I also get the z coordinate (if it has it)? Should I replace the dtype_point with np.dtype ((np.float64, 3))?
On the other hand, how to check if a polyline object has a z coordinate ?, with a feature class I would do arcpy.Describe (fc) .hasZ, however if I pass a polyline object to arcpy.Describe it returns an error.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience again, but assuming that a point has an itemsize of 16, and that the buffer returned by the SHAPE @ WKB token has a maximum of 1024, what happens when the number of points in a polyline * 16 exceeds the limit of 1024? that is, what happens when I have more than 64 points forming a polyline? I get an error indicating that the buffer size is not a multiple of the element size, since if I have 72 points for a polyline, multiplied by 16 gives 1152, a size outside the 1024 limit.

Comment: If the WKB is never longer than 1024 bytes then that sounds like an arcpy limitation, you should just unpack the points from geometry objects instead.  Geometry objects have a `has_z` attribute:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm#:~:text=SpatialReference-,has_z,-The%20Z%20state

Comment: Hello again.
I have been trying to check if a geometry has z values, however, when trying to use the has_z attribute I get an error indicating that it does not exist. So far I am getting out of the step checking if the z coordinate of the first point of the geometry is different from None, but this solution seems clumsy and does not convince me, any ideas?